# How to append values to dictionary In my Code Below

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this

```
var students = ["student_id":2,"present":0]
```

I get student_id from another ViewController So that I need to append them like this.

```
[49,29,12,4]

var students =["student_id":2,"present":0,"student_id":49,"present":0,"student_id":29,"present":0,"student_id":12,"present":0,"student_id":4,"present":0]
```

How Do I achieve This

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a dictionary with the same key name in Swift. If you try to do this then every time you will replace `student_id` and `present` values.

Instead of this, you can create an array of dictionary records as below.

```
var students: [[String : Int]] = [["student_id": 2, "present": 0]]

let ids = [49,29,12,4]
let anotherRecords = ids.map { ["student_id": $0, "present": 0] }
students.append(contentsOf: anotherRecords)

print(students)
```

And you got output like this.

```
  [["student_id": 2, "present": 0],
   ["student_id": 49, "present": 0], 
   ["present": 0, "student_id": 29],
   ["student_id": 12, "present": 0],
   ["present": 0, "student_id": 4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

To append values to a dictionary first you need to create a dictionary like below
and then append value in it

```
var students = [["student_id":2,"present":0]]
students.append(["student_id":49,"present":0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use dictionary where you were storing same key 'student_id'.
Id should be unique for dictionary.
Instead of this you can store like this

```
var students =[2:0]
students[49] = 0
students[29] = 0
students[12]= 0
students[4]= 0
```